# Construct table name dynamically in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am making a pentaho transformation and i have a table input step. My requirement was to pass the table input step dynamically as a variable and this i achieved by doing :

`select * from ${table_name}`

and when i run the transformation, i pass in the value of

```
table_name.
```

This works.

But my new requirement is: To pass the date as a variable and then construct a table name from the date based on the month and year
So for example:If I pass in 2012-01-31, I want a sql like this:

```
select * from xxx_201201_v
```

I cannot use a substr like this:

`select * from xxx_substr(${input_date} ,0,4)`

So I am confused how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Get Variables step so you have your date in a field. Then use steps to manipulate your strings and then pass the field to the Table Input step like this

select * from ?

Of course you should activate the option of the Table Input step to get fields from a previous step. If you have 2012-01-31 you can get 201201 using a find and replace step where you find "-" and replace it with nothing, and then cut the string so that you have the first 6 digits.